# get Array from another class and show it to a snackbar

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I tried to get a array from an adapter from my code

here is the array that i wanted to get from my adapter, named MakananAdapter :

```
private int[] JumlahPesan = {0,0,0,0};
```

The array is changing constantly since user will be deciding the amount that they want, here is the onBindViewHolder code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ImageView ivMakanan = holder.ivMakanan;
    TextView tvNamaHarga = holder.tvNamaMakanan;
    TextView tvKetersediaan = holder.tvKetersediaan;
    TextView tvHarga = holder.tvHargaMakanan;
    final TextView tvPesanan = holder.tvJumlahPesanan;
    Button btnTambah = holder.btnTambah;
    Button btnKurang = holder.btnKurang;

    ivMakanan.setImageResource(makanans.get(position).getGambarMakanan());
    tvNamaHarga.setText(makanans.get(position).getNamaMakanan());
    tvKetersediaan.setText("Stok : " + makanans.get(position).getStatusMakanan());
    tvHarga.setText("Harga : " + makanans.get(position).getHargaMakanan());
    btnTambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JumlahPesan[position]++;
            tvPesanan.setText(String.valueOf(JumlahPesan[position]));
        }
    });
    btnKurang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JumlahPesan[position]--;
            tvPesanan.setText(String.valueOf(JumlahPesan[position]));
        }
    });
}
```

as you can see i make a button that increase and decrease the data of the array

and i tried to get the array data to my activity, but i still get error.

my activity named PilihMakananActivity.class

here is the array to save the data from the adapter

```
private int[] Pesanan = {0,0,0,0};
```

and i tried to get the data in onResume

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    com.example.iotforcanteen.adapter.MakananAdapter coba = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<4 ; i++) {
        Pesanan [i]= coba.AmbilJumlahPesanan(i);
    }
}
```

and i tried to show it in a snackbar like this

```
btnKonfirmasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Snackbar.make(v, Pesanan[0] + Pesanan[1] + Pesanan[2] + Pesanan[3],Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Im so sorry if the code is so messy, because im new to android development.so is there any way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has error because you set to your adapter null value in onResume .
But in general I assume you use RecyclerView in code so the steps for using RecyclerView is important, first you must set LayoutManager for RecyclerView. Then make an adapter and set it to RecyclerView and I recommend you to do this steps in onCreate not onResume.
Here is a little example

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rec);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also make your array in adapter public or write getter for it. After calling setAdapter for RecyclerView, you can get your data in adapter. For example you can define a Button and in OnClickListener get the desired array(here is JumlahPesan) in adapter

Answer (score 0):

you aren't initiating this adapter (`null`) and few lines below trying to access data from it, this is `NullPointerException`

```
com.example.iotforcanteen.adapter.MakananAdapter coba = null;
for (int i = 0; i<4 ; i++) {
    Pesanan [i]= coba.AmbilJumlahPesanan(i);
}
```

make reference to already exitsting adapter atached to your `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, not freshly created and not initialised at all

note that `onResume` is called once at the beggining, thus your `Pesanan` won't have current data, only copy from start of `Activity`

maybe just get your values straightly when button pressed, without a copy of array in `Activity`:

```
btnKonfirmasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
            adapterAttachedToView.AmbilJumlahPesanan(0) + " " +
            adapterAttachedToView.AmbilJumlahPesanan(1) + " " + 
            adapterAttachedToView.AmbilJumlahPesanan(2) + " " + 
            adapterAttachedToView.AmbilJumlahPesanan(3),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

note that `Snackbar.make(` should take `View`, in which `Snackbar` will appear, not clicked `Button` (you are passing `v` to `Snackbar.make`)